# OpenGL Motion blur with the accumulation buffer in WxWidgets

Tags: c++, opengl, motion-blur

I'm trying to achieve a motion blur effect in my OpenGL application.

I read somewhere this solution, using the accumulation buffer:

```
 glAccum(GL_MULT, 0.90);
 glAccum(GL_ACCUM, 0.10);
 glAccum(GL_RETURN, 1.0);

 glFlush();
```

at the end of the rendering loop.

But nothing happens... What am I missing ?

### Additions after genpfault answer:

Indeed I did not asked for an accumulation buffer when I initialized my context.

So I tried to pass an array of attributes to the constructor of my `wxGLCanvas`, as described here: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.6/wx_wxglcanvas.html :

```
int attribList[]={ WX_GL_RGBA , WX_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER , WX_GL_MIN_ACCUM_RED, WX_GL_MIN_ACCUM_GREEN, WX_GL_MIN_ACCUM_BLUE, 0}
```

But all I get is a friendly *Seg fault*. Does someone understand how to use this ?

(no problems with `int attribList[]={ WX_GL_RGBA , WX_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER , 0}`)

Comment: I think you want something like:

int attribList[]={ WX_GL_RGBA , WX_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER , WX_GL_MIN_ACCUM_RED, 1, WX_GL_MIN_ACCUM_GREEN, 1, WX_GL_MIN_ACCUM_BLUE, 1, 0}

So the minimum bits for red/green/blue accum is 1.

Comment: Hmm. I'm still getting a Seg Fault...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to ask for an accumulation buffer when you request an OpenGL context from your windowing system.  You probably won't get one by default.

Comment: Hello, see my additions in the original question. Thank you for the answer :)